# Backbone Todos sample app

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I currently have a problem with the todos app example for Backbone. You can find my code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisg93/96tgP/3/

```
$ ->
  Todo = Backbone.Model.extend
    defaults:
      title: "Empty task"
      done:  false
      order: Todos.nextOrder()

  TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend
    model: Todo
    nextOrder: ->
      if not @length then 1 else (@model.last().get "order") + 1

  Todos = new TodoList()
```

When I try to run this minimalist code, I get an error saying that I can't call the method "nextOrder" of undefined. I have follow the tutorial and don't understand why this isn't working.

Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: im useless with what i assume is coffee script, but you should be getting / setting your ordering in the collection object.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your model's definition `Todos` is undefined.

I think you should make `order` a method of your model and refer to the collection that the model is part of, like this:

```
Todo = Backbone.Model.extend
    defaults:
      title: "Empty task"
      done:  false

    order: @collection.nextOrder()
```

Comment: Thank for your help. However, I still get the same problem with your patch. Is there anyone else who can help me? Thanks.